# Show Toast message in Quote Line Editor

Tags: visualforce, lightning-web-components, cpq, toast

I have a custom action in Quote Line Editor that launches VFpage with LWC. How to show toast message?

JS :

```
import { LightningElement,api,track } from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import getAccounts from '@salesforce/apex/QuoteLineRetriever.getAccounts';
import setAccountToQLG from '@salesforce/apex/AccountSetter.setAccountToQLG';


export default class QuoteLineDependencies extends LightningElement {

mapAccountsAndGroups = {}

showNotification(message, variant, title) {
    const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
        title: title,
        message: message,
        variant: variant,
    });
    this.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }

setMapAccount(event) {
    this.mapAccountsAndGroups[event.target.dataset.item] = event.target.value;
}

setAccounts() { // called by button
    this.toast();
    setAccountToQLG({QLGAndAccounts : this.mapAccountsAndGroups}).then(data =>{
        // this.toast();
    })
}
```

Aura App:

```
<aura:application extends="ltng:outApp" access="Global" >
    <aura:dependency resource="c:QuoteLineDependencies"/>
</aura:application>
```

VF Page :

```
<apex:page>

<apex:includeLightning />
<div id="lwcContainer"></div>
<script>
    var quoteId = "{!$CurrentPage.parameters.Id}";

$Lightning.use("c:QuoteLineDependenciesApp", function() {
        $Lightning.createComponent(
            "c:QuoteLineDependencies",
            {
                "navigateToList": navigateToList,
                "toast": showToast,
                recordId : quoteId
            },
            "lwcContainer",
            function(cmp) {
                console.log('Component Loaded');
            }
        );
    });
    
    function navigateToList(url) {
        if (typeof sforce !== 'undefined' && sforce && sforce.one) {
            sforce.one.navigateToURL(url);
        } else {
            window.location.href = url;
        }
    }
    
    function showToast() {
        console.log('showToast')
        console.log(typeof sforce);
        console.log(sforce);
        if (typeof sforce !== 'undefined' && sforce && sforce.one) {
            sforce.one.showToast({
                "message": "LWC Toast Message Inside VF Page Successfully",
                "type": "error"
            });
        }
    }
   </script>
</apex:page>
```

So I can see the "show Toast" message in the console, but I don't see any toast messages.
Any ideas how this can be done?